# Cakephp 3 - convert time from local timezone to UTC

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-3.0

i have a problem about the correct timezone when patching an entity. My post request looks like this:

```
   [
    'event_date' => '11.07.2019',
    'start_time' => '15:00',
    'end_time' => '16:00'
   ]
```

In my form I have a calendar and two fields where the user can choose the start and end time. Now these values are the timezone of the user. What I want is to convert those values to UTC and save them with my entity which has two `DATETIME` and one `DATE` fields.

To save it correctly without any validation error I have the following code for modifying the data before patching:

```
$event_date = new \DateTime($data['event_date']);

$start_time = new \DateTime($data['start_time']);
$end_time = new \DateTime($data['end_time']);

$start_time->setDate($event_date->format('Y'), $event_date->format('m'), $event_date->format('d'));
$end_time->setDate($event_date->format('Y'), $event_date->format('m'), $event_date->format('d'));

$data['start_time'] = $start_time;
$data['end_time'] = $end_time;

$data['event_date'] = $event_date;
```

But as you can see from the debug it converts it wrong. Cause I'm in the europe timezone it should have **2 hours** less.

```
[
    'event_date' => object(DateTime) {
        date => '2019-07-11 00:00:00.000000'
        timezone_type => (int) 3
        timezone => 'UTC'
    },
    'start_time' => object(DateTime) {
        date => '2019-07-11 15:00:00.000000'
        timezone_type => (int) 3
        timezone => 'UTC'
    },
    'end_time' => object(DateTime) {
        date => '2019-07-11 16:00:00.000000'
        timezone_type => (int) 3
        timezone => 'UTC'
    }
]
```

I configured my bootstrap like this:

```
Time::setToStringFormat('d.m.Y H:i');
Time::setJsonEncodeFormat('d.m.Y H:i');

FrozenTime::setToStringFormat('d.m.Y H:i');
FrozenTime::setJsonEncodeFormat('d.m.Y H:i');

Date::setToStringFormat('d.m.Y');
Date::setJsonEncodeFormat('d.m.Y');

FrozenDate::setToStringFormat('d.m.Y');
FrozenDate::setJsonEncodeFormat('d.m.Y');


Type::build('time')
    ->useImmutable();
Type::build('date')
    ->useImmutable();

Type::build('datetime')
    // ->useImmutable()
    ->useLocaleParser()
    ->setLocaleFormat('d.m.Y H:i:ss');
```

Can someone help me here? I'm a bit confused...

Comment: can you show your database configuration (without login/pass/host) and app configuration in your config/app.php?

Answer (score 1):

Well, you're not using the Date and DateTime objects from Cake at all: `\DateTime` this mean it is the plain php [DateTime](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php) object.

Fix that and use the correct objects and see what happens then. Also make sure you configured your default time zone correctly. Have a read: https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/core-libraries/time.html